# Deleting an item from Listview with a Delete Button

Tags: android

I'm getting a null pointer as the view from where my program is right now is main activity but then, the main activity is a listview containing views of expense_entry.xml. Each entry has a 3 textviews and a delete button. This is my onCreate in the main activity. The question is when I do a findViewById(deleteButton)... If there are 25 buttons, how does it know which button its referring to? which is why I'm getting a null pointer.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewlist);
        dbHelper = new RecordsDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();
        //Add some data
//        dbHelper.insertSomeRecords();
        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        displayListView();
//        setContentView(R.layout.expense_entry);
            Button deleteBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do something
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
//                    final ConstraintLayout c = this;
                    for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < parent.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
                        View view = parent.getChildAt(2);
                        if (view.getParent() == parent) {
                            dbHelper.deleteSingleRow(String.valueOf(view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDateTime)));
                            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }}
```

[Main activity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78xwn.png)
[entry.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HftyO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the delete button functionality in your listview adapter class and call notifydatasetchanged()